# Printing pages in InDesign file with sections

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am having trouble printing pages in an InDesign file that has sections. 
I have two sections. The first has the 5 pages of a book (that I do not want to have numbers). The second section has 195 pages. The first page in this section is actually page 1.

I can't print any of the pages in the first section unless I print the entire book. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

When printing sections, you need to type in the section name. For example:

- typing 'A' will print your entire 'A' section, where 'A' is your first section name (first 5 pages)
- typing 'B' will print your entire 'B' (second) section (next 195 pages)
- typing '+1,+2,+3,+4,+5' ignores section names and prints the very first 5 pages in your document. More useful info [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/printing-documents.html) or [here](https://indesignsecrets.com/solving-printing-exporting-confusion.php).

[image]